# C++ - glibc detected

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I have a program which runs perfect on my OS X system but whenever I run it on a linux machine it throws an error stating:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x08bd6008 ***
a.out: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am using c++11 library. Is it because of that?

This is my program: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a0e6f52e9929d08341c2

Comment: Side note: It's amusing how badly this message is worded, in that it sounds like it means "a glibc was detected" (the problem was a glibc) instead of "glibc detected this problem" (glibc is the thing that noticed the problem)

Comment: The problem is probably memory corruption. Have you tried running your program under valgrind (a tool for finding various memory problems)?

Comment: Next time post a testcase _in_ the question please. In fact, you should fix _this_ question too.

Comment: If you're using C++11, you don't need `process* pArray = new process;` or `atoi`.

Comment: ChaniLastname: How many elements big is your "array" pArray?

Comment: @immibis It can go up to 10000. But its defined by user input

Comment: @ChaniLastname how many do you allocate?

Comment: Well I just added `pArray = new process[numProcessesRequired];` in the main function and just made the declaration to `process* pArray;` and it worked. No issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your `pArray` is a pointer to just one dynamically-allocated `process`, but you're later treating it as if it were an array of an indeterminate number of `process` objects.

If this ran okay for you on your OSX machine then that's only because this sort of programming mistake cannot be guaranteed to be automatically detected. You got *lucky* on your Linux machine at that particular time.

Your easiest fix is to pre-allocate *N* `process` objects and cap `numProcessesRequired` at that value:

```
static const size_t MAX_NUM_PROCESSES = 16;
process* pArray = new process[MAX_NUM_PROCESSES];

// later...
numProcessesRequired = atoi(argv[1]);
assert(numProcessesRequired <= MAX_NUM_PROCESSES);
```

But you should really be using a `std::vector` for stuff like this.

Comment: This tells me the assertion failed: 
`Assertion failed: (numProcessesRequired <= MAX_NUM_PROCESSES), function main, file main.cpp, line 84.
Abort trap: 6`

Comment: @ChaniLastnamé: So input a valid value for `numProcessesRequired` or increase `MAX_NUM_PROCESSES` to suit your needs.

Comment: I just added `pArray = new process[numProcessesRequired];` in the main function and just made the declaration to `process* pArray;` and it worked. No issues.

Comment: @ChaniLastnamé: No, you have UB. `numProcessesRequired` is `0` until your user input, so you are overrunning your array again. Please listen to me and use the solution I have provided; each part of it serves a vital purpose. (It's kind of funny that you think "it worked. No issues" is a sign that it's actually correct and will always be okay, when you came here in the first place with a program that had "worked" with "no issues" for you on one system but then broke on another!!)